# The requested module 'node:stream' does not provide an export named 'getDefaultHighWaterMark'

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, syntax-error, node-modules, nuxtjs3

I am working on Nuxt 3 project and i got the error `The requested module 'node:stream' does not provide an export named 'getDefaultHighWaterMark'` when I re-installed the node using the npm i.

I have deleted the`node-module` and `package-lock.json` files and try to run npm I but it returns an error

I have checked with different node versions like `v19.3.0` `v18.0.0` but it does not work with any version.

I have used the Element Plus with this nuxt 3 project

Here are the all error lines

**npm start**

```html
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'node-addon-api@7.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^16 || ^18 || >= 20' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.0.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

> postinstall
> nuxt prepare

Nuxi 3.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                               16:55:21

 ERROR  The requested module 'node:stream' does not provide an export named 'getDefaultHighWaterMark'                                                                                                    16:55:22

  import {PassThrough as PassThroughStream, getDefaultHighWaterMark} from 'node:stream';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:stream' does not provide an export named 'getDefaultHighWaterMark'
  at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123:21)
  at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:518:24)
  at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15)
  at async installModule (/home/project/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:416:3)
  at async initNuxt (/home/project/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1825:7)
  at async loadNuxt (/home/project/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1857:5)
  at async loadNuxt (/home/project/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:493:19)
  at async Object.invoke (/home/project/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/prepare.mjs:30:18)
  at async _main (/home/project/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- nuxt prepare
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue.

Installing the latest node version helped me. Before i was using Node: v18.0.3

Now i have updated to: v21.6.2 and no longer have this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try:

```bash
npm install --force
```